# Need help finding a hell forge in the Underworld

Tags: terraria-console

So I heard that hell forges can be found in the red brick houses in The Underworld, but I keep getting confused with the obsidian brick houses. Help?

I've tried the dungeon but I couldn't find any. I'm on Xbox 360.

Comment: Is this the PC version, console version, or mobile version?

Comment: @DanielG My bad, it was originally tagged as Xbox 360 but I removed it because it's not about the console itself. I didn't realize the platform is actually relevant for Terraria.

Answer (score 0):

From the terraria wiki (http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Hellforge):

> Please note that in the console version, the Hellforge spawns in the
>   Deep Underground, or right above the Underworld. This is fixed in the
>   most recent update, but worlds generated prior to the update will
>   still have hellforges above the underworld in the stone layer.

**EDIT 1:** Hellforges are NOT located in The Underworld, they're located in the level just above it and are often submerged in lava.

**EDIT 2:** [official Terraria Wiki page for Hellforge](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hellforge#Notes%22official%20Terraria%20Wiki%20page%20for%20hellforge%22) says:

> In the Console version, Hellforges can spawn just above the Underworld.

Comment: i have the latest update

Comment: How old is your world? Was it generated with the current version?

Comment: [This is the Official Terraria Wiki page for the Hellforge.](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hellforge)  I generally avoid wikia hosted sites when an alternative is available, because they are slow to plagiarize from more authoritative sites.

Comment: @Jeff As mentioned on the Wikia page, worlds generated prior to the update will not be changed by an update. You'll need to generate a new world to see the effects of any change to world generation, such as block, treasure, or furniture placement.

Comment: I couldn't find them above the Underworld.